# Atualizar uma coluna com os 2 últimos dígitos de outra coluna

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela de assuntos de reuniões, com as colunas ID, ASSUNTO, ATA. Antigamente o ID dessa tabela exibia "ATA-ASSUNTO" (por exemplo 102-02) mas recentemente foi retirado o hífen para poder implementar o auto incremento.
Eu gostaria de selecionar os últimos 2 dígitos da coluna ID, pois eles correspondem ao numero do assunto, e assim, passar esses 2 dígitos para a coluna ASSUNTO.

Tentei:

```
UPDATE reuniao_assunto
SET assunto = SELECT RIGHT(reuniao_assunto.id,2)
FROM reuniao_assunto
```

Mas não retorna resultado.

Apenas:

```
SELECT RIGHT(reuniao_assunto.id,2)
FROM reuniao_assunto
```

Me retorna os valores que eu preciso, mas não consigo inseri-los na outra coluna.

Comment: *"u gostaria de selecionar os últimos 2 dígitos da coluna ID.."* olá Guilherme, e qual é a dúvida especificamente? já tem a query, tem algum problema com ela? não retornar o valor experado? explique melhor a dúvida/problema

Comment: essa query não funcionou, e gostaria que alguém pudesse ajudar a concerta-la. Elas simplesmente não retorna resultado.

Comment: *"Elas simplesmente não retorna resultado"* isso simplesmente não faz sentido. Veja aqui o exemplo que fiz com os dados que informou na pergunta, e o `right` retorna os dados (fiz o teste ainda usar tanto `varchar` com `char`) :   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dca440/3

Comment: Acrescentei lá, o SELECT está funcionando, mas o UPDATE não. Essa é minha dificuldade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema é simplesmente o `SET`.

Note que, no `UPDATE` já definiou a tabela "reuniao_assunto", por isso, como deseja fazer update a partir de um valor da mesma tabela, não é necessário fazer um `SELECT`, pode simplesmente fazer assim:

```
UPDATE reuniao_assunto
   SET assunto = RIGHT(reuniao_assunto.id,2);
```

Veja aqui funcionando: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1a92c0/1)

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.